# Understanding secp256k1 elliptic curve subtraction formula

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-arithmetic, secp256k1

**Point doubling formula**

*Calculate the slope*

$\lambda = (3\times Q_x^2) \times$ pow($2 \times Q_y$, -1, $p$) % $p$

*Calculate the new point coordinates*

$R_x = (λ^2 - 2 \times Q_x)$ % $p$

$R_y = (\lambda \times (Q_x - R_x) - Q_y)$ % $p$

**Point addition formula**

*Calculate the slope*

$\lambda = (Q_y - G_y) \times$ pow($Q_x - G_x, -1, p$) % $p$

*Calculate the new point coordinates*

$R_x =  (λ^2 - Q_x - G_x)$ % $p$

$R_y = (\lambda \times (Q_x - R_x) - Q_y)$ % $p$

**Point subtraction formula**

*Calculate the slope*

$\lambda = (Q_y + G_y) \times$ pow($G_x - Q_x, -1, p)$ % $p$

*Calculate the new point coordinates*

$R_x = (λ^2 - Q_x - G_x)$ % $p$

$R_y = (\lambda \times (R_x - Q_x) - Q_y)$ % $p$

1. **Point Doubling (Elliptic Curve Operation):**

   *Slope Calculation*: $\lambda = (3 \times Q_x^2) \times (2 \times Q_y)^{-1}$ % $p$

   This calculates the slope of the tangent line to the curve at the point $Q$. It's used to find the coordinates of the new point resulting from the doubling operation on the elliptic curve.
2. **Point Addition (Elliptic Curve Operation):**

   *Slope Calculation:* $\lambda = (Q_y - G_y) \times (Q_x - G_x)^{-1}$ % $p$

   This calculates the slope of the line passing through point $Q$ and $G$ on the curve. It's used to find the coordinates of the new point resulting from the addition operation on the elliptic curve.

How is the slope calculated in the point subtraction formula for the secp256k1 elliptic curve, what is its significance in the operation?. Is the slope still calculating the line passing through $G$ and $Q$?

I know negeting a point and adding it to another point can still be used to achieve subtraction but I want to understand how the above subtraction formula works.

Comment: Point substruction is just negating the point then adding. Nothing is special there.

Comment: I know negating the point can still be used to achieve subtraction but am talking about the formula

Comment: Then use the negated values the formula that you need.

Comment:  I said I know negating a point and adding it to another point would work but I want to understand how the above subtraction formula works

Comment: Insert $-y_2$ into the addition formula and you have the negation formula.

Comment: if you don't understand what @kelalaka is suggesting, you need to learn/study some math; the statement "how the above formula works" is not really a valid question. EC point addition, subtraction etc. are *defined* as certain operations and proved to have some required properties. Maybe you can expand further in the body of the question on what you understand "how it works" to mean.

Comment: I understand what @kelalaka said